# Share Point Validation Settings - Formula

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I am trying to set a rule within a SP list which will prevent users from selecting the status as "Closed" whilst a numerical field has anything greater than 0.

I've tried playing around but I am far from a formula wiz :(.

Thanks,

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a List Validation. In List Settings > Validation Settings, put this formula :

```
=IF(num>0,IF(status="Closed",FALSE,TRUE),TRUE)
```

Basically : 
If num is greater than 0, check for status closed, otherwise return true (valid). If status is closed, return false (error), otherwise return true (valid)

This will only work with choice column, not lookup.

Comment: You can shorten it to: **AND( num , NOT(status="Closed") )**

Answer (score 1):

A is your choice column and B is your numeric field.

```
=IF([A]<>"Closed",[B]>0,TRUE)
```